# How to manage different Serverless (with AWS Lambda) environments (ie "dev" and "prod")

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I want to create a separate 'dev' AWS Lambda with my Serverless service.

I have deployed my production, 'prod', environment and tried to then deploy a development, 'dev', environment so that I can trial features without affecting customer experience.

In order to deploy the 'dev' environment I have:

1. Created a new `serverless-dev.yml` file
2. Updated the `stage` and `profile` fields in my .yml file:

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-2
  profile: dev
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 30
```

3. Also update the `resources.Resources.<Logical Id>.Properties.RoleName` value, as if I try to use the same role as my 'prod' Lambda, I get this message: `clearbit-lambda-role-prod already exists in stack`

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    <My Logical ID>:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        Path: /my/cust/path/
        RoleName: clearbit-lambda-role-dev # Change this name
```

4. Run command: `sls deploy -c serverless-dev.yml`

Is this the conventional method to achieve this? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverless Framework has support for stages out of the box. You don't need a separate configuration, you can just specify `--stage <name-of-stage>` when running .e.g `sls deploy` and it will automatically use that stage. All resources created by the Framework under the hood are including `stage` in it's names or identifiers. If you are defining some extra resources in `resources` section, you need to change them, or make sure they include stage in their names. You can get the current stage in configuration with `${sls:stage}` and use that to construct names that are e.g. prefixed with stage.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds exactly like what I thought I'd be missing!

Comment: ... EDIT: If I run the command `serverless deploy --stage dev` I get `<service>-<stage> already exists in stack` (where stage is `prod`). I think I'll need to follow the instructions in the docs (https://www.serverless.com/blog/stages-and-environments) from scratch next time for it to work.

Comment: It's hard to say based on just that command, but by default, the stage is `dev`. Maybe you deployed your service already to that stage and some resource would be now duplicated?